# why git pull leaves merge annotation in the code and commit the merge

Tags: git, merge

I tried to push my local change to remote and see the following errors:

> hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is
>   behind

Then, I use `git pull origin remote_branch_name`. The pull is done without issues. However, when I check the change files, the git leaves tons of annotation in the code and render it un-compilable.

For example:
git adds the following to the code:

```
<<<<<<<<<HEAD
void function();

=========
>>>>>>>>
```

When I check `git status -s`, it shows nothing and git has commited the change.

Question> Does anyone know why it happens like this?

Thank you

== Update the pull output ==

```
$ git pull origin remote_branch_name
Password for 'http://xxx@bitbucket':

 * branch            remote_branch_name -> FETCH_HEAD
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 libs/file1.h       |   4 +++
 libs/file2.cpp     |   7 +++++

  2 files changed, 153 insertions(+)
$ git status -s
```

Comment: You say the pull was done without issues. Are you sure it didn't say there was a merge conflict? It looks like there was. Try running `git mergetool`

Comment: @Tone, please check my update post. Yes, I didn't see any conflict.

Comment: Sorry don't know then. Maybe somebody else will have an answer.

Comment: I'd check the origin for conflict markers, perhaps someone decided to commit those.

Comment: @Hasturkun, yes, you are right!

Comment: @Brian done. thank you

Comment: Somebody else botched a merge, and then you pulled it down. You can find the offending commit with `git blame`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause of this problem is due to the incorrect checked-in file that has all those unfinished merge annotation.

The solution is to first to pull those incorrect files and then manually correct those annotation. Finally push the change to the remote and it will works.

The reason I cannot force push is because this function has been disabled by remote branch.

Thank you